# Iteratively removing list items without altering indices, is using a 'DELETEME' string a sound approach?

Tags: python, list, loops, indexing

I have a number of lists created by reading CSVs where each index represents a data point. So:

```
# names = ['name1','name2', 'name3', 'name4']
# data1 = ['1', '2', '3', '4']
# data2 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

is equivalent to:

> name1,1,a

I need to remove certain data points, and the easiest way seems to be by index:

```
del names[1]
del data1[1]
del data2[1]
# names = ['name1', 'name3', 'name4']
```

However, I am iterating over the lists using indices and don't want to alter them until the loop is finished. My solution is to replace the items to be deleted with a unique string, and then delete them later:

```
names[1] = 'DELETEME'
data1[1] = 'DELETEME'
data2[1] = 'DELETEME'
# names = ['name1','DELETEME', 'name3', 'name4']
```

Is this a sound practice or should I do something else?

**EDIT** Wow, thanks for all the responses. It'll take me a bit to test different approaches. For those who asked, here's an additional code snippet:

```
# read CSV file. create lists
names = ['name1', 'name2', 'name3', 'name4']
data1 = [1, 32.018, 3, 4]
data2 = [5, -22, 6, 7]

# master list of names to look for
master = ['name2', 'name5']

for i,n in enumerate(names):
    # find intersections with master list, get indices
    # ...
    matches = [1] # index of 'names2'

    # iterate through matches
    for m in matches:
         # specify a criterion for deleting/modifying data points
         # example:
        if data1[m] == 32.018 and data2[m] == -22:
            del names[m]
            del data1[m]
            del data2[m]
        # specify additional criteria using additional if statements
        # ...
```

Comment: can you include the code which "iterates over the lists"? does that code determine which indices to delete (later)?

Comment: Consider using `deleted = object()` as a unique placeholder to assign to deleted items. Then you can check for deletion with `data1[i] is deleted`.

Comment: @shx2: added a code snippet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could keep a memo of the indexes to delete and then apply them in reverse order after your other work is done.

```
delete_memo = []
for i in xrange(len(names)):
    if CONDITION_FOR_DELETION:
        delete_memo.append(i)
delete_memo.reverse()
for i in delete_memo:
    del names[i]
    del data1[i]
    del data2[i]
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how you would remove entries while iterating without skipping any or using a "deleted token".

```
i = 0
while i < len(names):
    if CONDITION_FOR_DELETION:
        del names[i]
        del data1[i]
        del data2[i]
    else:
        i += 1
```

Comment: I like it but since the user wants to delete after processing, I provided an alternate.

Answer (score 0):

This seems overly complex, why not hash the key/values into a `dict` and then delete the key/value pairs as you go?

```
>>> tst = {1:3}
>>> del(tst[1])
>>> tst
{}
```

you'll of course have to iterate over the dict instead (and not worry about the index) but I usuaully find that easier anyway

Answer (score 0):

That is not bad practice, the way you are doing it, but you could iterate like this:

```
data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
i = 0
while i < len(data):
    if data[i] == 3:
        del data[i]
    else:
        i += 1
```

Basically, only increase the counter `i` if you don't remove the item from the list.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your needs, you could also consider iterating over a copy of the list.

If you post a copy of your code snippet it might help.